# But where does logarithmic differentiation come from?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I'm familiar with the formula:\begin{equation}(\ln(f(x))'=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\end{equation} and what it's used for, but how is the formula derived? I can't seem to find anything about the log-derivative that actually provides a proof of it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Use the chain rule for the derivative of a composite function

Comment: What’s the derivative of $\ln u$?

Comment: The more interesting question might be why is the derivative of logarithm the (multiplicative) inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the chain rule for the derivative of a composite function.

Can you now see how to prove the formula?